# Showing equicontinuity for the family of polynomials of degree n or less on a specific interval

Tags: real-analysis

This is kind of a low-rent version of some more abstract proofs related to equicontinuity on compact sets, but this is a version I'm trying to prove.

Suppose $N \in \Bbb{N}$. Let $F_N$ be the family of all polynomials of degree at most N, with coeffcients in $[-1,1]$.
Prove that $F_N$ is equibounded and equicontinuous on [0; 2].

So far I have that for M = sup $|\sum_{j=0}^{N} a_jx^j| \leq \sum_{j=0}^{N} 2^j = N2^N$, we have $F_N \leq M$. So the family is equibounded.

I'm thinking I want $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$. Now I'm trying to get an estimate on $|f_N(x) - f_N(y)|= $
$|\sum_{j=0}^{N} a_jx^j - \sum_{j=0}^{N} a_jy^j| \leq$
$\sum_{j=1}^{N} |x^j - y^j| \leq$....

and at this point I'm struggling with the estimate. I'm not confident I know how to factor this guy. I know I need to pull out an |x-y|, but is $\sum_{j=2}^{N} |x-y||x^j + y^j|$ correct? And then how best to estimate the |x^j + y^j| for $2 \leq j \leq N$?

Answer (score 2):

The derivatives are uniformly bounded because their coefficients are in $[-N,N]$. By MVT the family is equi-continuous.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is
$$x^j-y^j = (x-y)(x^{j-1}+x^{j-2}y+\cdots+xy^{j-2}+y^{j-1})$$
Since $|x^p|\leq 2^p$ and $|y^q|\leq 2^q$, we have $|x^py^q|\leq 2^{p+q}$. This should allow you to bound the sum in the right factor by $2^{j-1}j$.